# If two dice are thrown and one die lands on 2, find the probability that the product of the two numbers is exactly 6.

Tags: probability

Two fair dice are thrown and the product of the two numbers is recorded. If one die lands on 2, find the probability that:

The product of the two numbers is exactly $6$.

My turn:
$P(6 |2) = \frac{P(6\cap 2)}{P(2)} = \frac{\frac{2}{36}}{\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{1}{3} $

But

When I tried it again using the tree diagram, I got the answer is $12$ pairs which each of them has 2, and the product is 6 for just two pairs of them, so the answer would be $\frac{1}{6}$.
What is wrong?

Comment: there are $11$ pairs with one of them land on $2$.

Comment: Do you mean that i have counted the pair (2,2) twice ? But even if , the answer would be $\frac{2}{11}$ which is also different @abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you wrote in the comments is correct.

If two fair dice are thrown, the statement one die lands on 2 implicitly means *at least* one die lands on 2.

We can calculate the probability this occurs directly.  Say we have a blue die and a green die.  Then each outcome can be expressed in the form $(b, g)$, where $b$ is the number that appears on the top face of the blue die and $g$ is the number that appears on the top face of the blue die.  Then we want the probability that $b = 2$ or $g = 2$.

The probability that event $E$ occurs or event $F$ occurs is
$$\Pr(E \cup F) = \Pr(E) + \Pr(F) - \Pr(E \cap F)$$
Why?  If we simply add the probability that event $F$ occurs to the probability that event $E$ occurs, we will have counted those cases in which both event $E$ and event $F$ occurs twice, once when we count the event in which they both occur as an event in which event $E$ occurs and once we count it as an event in which event $F$ occurs.  Since we only want to count events in which both events $E$ and $F$ occur once, we must subtract them from the total.

In our case,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(b = 2 \cup g = 2) & = \Pr(b = 2) + \Pr(g = 2) - \Pr(b = 2 \cap g = 2)\\ 
                      & = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} - \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
                      & = \frac{11}{36}
\end{align*}
where we have assumed the outcomes of the rolls of the blue die and the green die are independent.

However, it is simpler to calculate the probability that at least one die lands on 2 by subtracting the probability that neither die lands on 2 from $1$.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(b = 2 \cup g = 2) & = 1 - \Pr(b \neq 2 \cap g \neq 2)\\
                      & = 1 - \Pr(b \neq 2)\Pr(g \neq 2)\\
                      & = 1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\\
                      & = \frac{11}{36}
\end{align*}
Again, we have assumed the outcomes of the rolls of the blue die and the green die are independent.

In your initial calculation, you calculated the probability that a single die lands on 2 rather than the probability that at least one die lands on 2.  As you realized after reading abc's comment, you counted $(2, 2)$ twice when you tried to solve the problem using a tree diagram.

There are only two ways to obtain a product of $6$ if at least one die lands on 2.  They are $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$.  Hence, the probability that the product of the outcomes of the two fair dice is $6$ given that one die lands on $2$ is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{product is $6$} \mid \text{at least one die lands on 2}) & = \frac{\Pr(\text{product is $6$ and at least one die lands on 2})}{\Pr(\text{at least one die lands on 2})}\\
& = \frac{\frac{2}{36}}{\frac{11}{36}}\\
& = \frac{2}{11}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 0):

My obvious but crude approach would be to list all possible combinations as in this case there are only 36:

(1,1), (1,2), ... through to (6,6).  Cross out all combinations which do not have at least one 2 then count the number of combinations which multiply to six and divide by the number of combinations you have not crossed out.

The second approach is to say what combinations multiply to six:

Either you roll a 2 first and a 3 second or you roll a 3 first and a 2 second making 2 possibilities.

Now how many combinations have at least one 2:

Either the first dice is a 2 (and we don't care what the other is) or the first dice is not a 2 and the second is.  Note: this stops us counting (2,2) twice.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise.